# Django: Iterating over multiple instances of a single model in a view

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm relatively new to Django and face a problem that I couldn't solve yet:
I have two models which look like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    char1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    char2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Entry(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    choice = models.IntegerField()
```

I have stored many Items in my database, and I want basically in one view to randomly iterate through all the stored Items, and for each Item display char1 and char2 with an IntegerField and a 'next' button, that stores a new Entry (with the actual Item, and typed integer) in my database and directs me to the next (random) Item.

During research I found for example the form wizard and formsets, but this is not what I want, the wizard needs multiple form models that he can display successive, but I want to display (randomly) each instance of only one model (Item) and store one Entry for each.

I hope someone can give me a hint where to look for, because nowhere I found a documentation/tutorial for this use case, and since I'm not very experienced with Django, I can't figure it out at the moment...

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly iterate through all the stored Items"?

Comment: I have stored like 3 Items, item1, item2, item3.  
Whenever I call the site, it displays all Items in a different order, like on the first call: item2, *submit*, item3, *submit*, item1. on the next call, e.g. item1 ist displayed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your title, the problem is the iterating over multiple items from a single (possibly random/unsorted) model.

If I'm not mistaken, what you are looking for is [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/).  From that text, a small example is:

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)

>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> p.page_range
[1, 2]
```

Although a list is shown above, `Paginator` can also be used on Django QuerySets, and it's functionality incorporated into Django Templates.

Let me know if this isn't what you're after.

Cheer.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, I think this might exactly be what I need for this, don't know why I didn't get to there and stuck up with forms and wizards.. I will try this out!

Comment: No problem!  Sometimes findings out the name of the thing you need to look into can be just as tricky as looking into it.

Comment: Right. And I tested it out, this is what I was looking for, thanks again!
One question remains though, can I now for each page I show create one new Entry object and save it to my database after the users submits some data?

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to combine forms and pagination, as long as your views, models, and templates are setup to do so.  Give it a try, and if you get stuck, come on back!

Answer (score 0):

Paulo Bu's answer provides the way to get the random ordering in the first place from Django's AP. The tricky part about what you're doing is that it's not really [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Constraints) to save the particular random ordering of the items between page loads, because that is not stateless. By default, your randomly ordered queryset is going to fall out of existence as soon as you serve the request, and there will be no guarantee that you will circulate through all the items instead of getting repeats and misses. So you'll want to save that ordering. There are a bunch of options for how you might approach this:

1. Serve the entire randomized list of item IDs with every request, and have the backend serve up the data for the current item by index
2. Serve all of the data -- full items and entries -- then you can either render everything client-side
3. Store the randomized list as a session variable
4. Store a permanent random ordering of the items by adding a float between 0 and 1 to every Item, ordering on that float, and starting at a random index (if you don't care whether each user has the same overall permutation)

Comment: Okay, thank you for these information! I think point 4 is out, because it's important that each user gets a different permutation, too.
But point 1 to 3 look good, thank you for this! I will definitively try this out!